# Progress bar freezing on window 8

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

HI i am using a frame over which i am loading a dialog. The singleton dialog holds a progress bar. 
I have created my own swing worker. i am controlling the construct method of swing worker(which functions like doInBackground method).
I am trying to call hidedialog from an external class. The dialog gets stuck sometimes. How do i solve it . It works fine on win7 but fails on win8.

```
  public class LoadingProgressDialogSingleton extends com.manu.scpoweb.common.ds.client.swing.dialog.Dialog {
    protected static LoadingProgressDialogSingleton oneAndOnlyProgressDialog = null;
    JProgressBar progressBar = null;
    DFULoadStatusBean dfuLoadStatusBean = null;
    double progress;
    int progressComplete = 0;
    BusinessObjectUserContext uc = null;
    CopyProgressBarWorker copyProgressBarWorker = null;
    ProgressBarWorker progressBarWorker = null;
    public static synchronized LoadingProgressDialogSingleton getProgressDialog(IApplicationContext iApplicationContext, ClientDataManager dataManager){
        if (oneAndOnlyProgressDialog == null){
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog = new LoadingProgressDialogSingleton(iApplicationContext.getParentFrame(),
                    iApplicationContext.getResource(APMConstants.RESOURCE_BUNDLE, "ProgressBar.Loading"), Boolean.TRUE);

            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.progressBar.setValue(0);
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 20));
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.progressBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));

            JLabel label = new JLabel(iApplicationContext.getResource(APMConstants.RESOURCE_BUNDLE, "ProgressBar.Reloading"));

            JPanel center_panel = new JPanel();
            center_panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 6, 2, 6);
            center_panel.add(label, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            center_panel.add(oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.progressBar, gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            center_panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue(), gbc);

            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.getContentPane().add(center_panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center on screen
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 107));
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.uc = new BusinessObjectUserContext(iApplicationContext.getUser().getUserName(),
                               iApplicationContext.getUserLocale());
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.uc.setAttributes(dataManager.getUserContext().getUserPreferences());
        }
        return oneAndOnlyProgressDialog;

    }
    public void showDialog(java.util.List<AttributeUUID> promoOfferKeysOnly){

        final Thread showDialogThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    toFront();
                    show();
                }
            });
        showDialogThread.start();

        if (promoOfferKeysOnly != null && promoOfferKeysOnly.size() > 0 ) {
           progressBarWorker = new ProgressBarWorker();
           BusinessObjectUserContext uc = new BusinessObjectUserContext(oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.uc.getUserName(),
                   oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.uc.getLocale());
           uc.setAttributes(oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.uc.getUserPreferences());
           progressBarWorker.setBusinessObjectUserContext(uc);
           progressBarWorker.setDataKey(promoOfferKeysOnly.get(0));
           progressBarWorker.start();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void hideDialog(){
        if (oneAndOnlyProgressDialog != null){
            ProgressBarWorker worker = oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.progressBarWorker;
            CopyProgressBarWorker copyWorker = oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.copyProgressBarWorker;
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.dispose();

            if(oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.isShowing())
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog.setVisible(false);
            oneAndOnlyProgressDialog = null;
            if (worker!=null){
                worker.setProgressComplete();
            }
            if (copyWorker!=null){
                copyWorker.setCopyCompleted();
            }
        }
    }
    protected LoadingProgressDialogSingleton(Frame iParent, String iTitle, boolean iModal) {
        super(iParent, iTitle, iModal);
    }
    class ProgressBarWorker extends SwingWorker {
        BusinessObjectUserContext uc = null;
        AttributeUUID dataKey = null;

        public AttributeUUID getDataKey() {
            return dataKey;
        }

        public void setDataKey(AttributeUUID dataKey) {
            this.dataKey = dataKey;
        }
        public void setProgressComplete(){
            progressComplete = 100;
        }
        public Object construct() {
            progressComplete = 0;
            EventQueue queue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue();
            if (queue instanceof ManuEventQueue) {
                try {
                    JAASUtilities.runAs(((ManuEventQueue) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue()).getSubject(),
                            new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
                                public Object run() throws Exception {
                                    long totalDFUsCnt = 0;
                                    long basePriceLoadedCnt = 0;
                                    long baseCostLoadedCnt = 0;
                                    long udasLoadedCnt = 0;
                                    long histLoadedCnt = 0;
                                    long fcstLoadedCnt = 0;
                                    progressBar.setValue(5);
                                    //Initialize progress property.
                                    while (progressComplete < 5) {
                                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                                            break;
                                        if (dataKey != null) {
                                            dfuLoadStatusBean = APMController.getDFULoadStatus(dataKey, uc);
                                            if (dfuLoadStatusBean == null || !dfuLoadStatusBean.isStrated()) {
                                                Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
                                                continue;
                                            } else {
                                                if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getNumberOfDFUsInOffer() != null && totalDFUsCnt != dfuLoadStatusBean.getNumberOfDFUsInOffer().getSecond()) {
                                                    totalDFUsCnt = dfuLoadStatusBean.getNumberOfDFUsInOffer().getSecond();
                                                    progressBar.setValue(10);
                                                }
                                                if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfuBaseCostStatusAndCountPair() != null && (baseCostLoadedCnt != totalDFUsCnt)) {
                                                    if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfuBaseCostStatusAndCountPair().getFirst()) {
                                                        baseCostLoadedCnt = totalDFUsCnt;
                                                        progressComplete++;

                                                    } else {
                                                        baseCostLoadedCnt = dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfuBaseCostStatusAndCountPair().getSecond();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfuBasePriceStatusAndCountPair() != null && (basePriceLoadedCnt != totalDFUsCnt)) {
                                                    if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfuBasePriceStatusAndCountPair().getFirst()) {
                                                        basePriceLoadedCnt = totalDFUsCnt;
                                                        progressComplete++;

                                                    } else {
                                                        basePriceLoadedCnt = dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfuBasePriceStatusAndCountPair().getSecond();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusUDAStatusAndCountPair() != null && (udasLoadedCnt != totalDFUsCnt)) {`enter code here
                                                    if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusUDAStatusAndCountPair().getFirst()) {
                                                        udasLoadedCnt = totalDFUsCnt;
                                                        progressComplete++;

                                                    } else {
                                                        udasLoadedCnt = dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusUDAStatusAndCountPair().getSecond();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusHISTStatusAndCountPair() != null && (histLoadedCnt != totalDFUsCnt)) {
                                                    if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusHISTStatusAndCountPair().getFirst()) {
                                                        histLoadedCnt = totalDFUsCnt;
                                                        progressComplete++;
                                                    } else {
                                                        histLoadedCnt = dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusHISTStatusAndCountPair().getSecond();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusFCSTStatusAndCountPair() != null && (fcstLoadedCnt != totalDFUsCnt)) {
                                                    if (dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusFCSTStatusAndCountPair().getFirst()) {
                                                        fcstLoadedCnt = totalDFUsCnt;
                                                        progressComplete++;
                                                    } else {
                                                        fcstLoadedCnt = dfuLoadStatusBean.getDfusFCSTStatusAndCountPair().getSecond();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                if (totalDFUsCnt != 0.0)
                                                    progress = (((baseCostLoadedCnt / totalDFUsCnt * 80) + (basePriceLoadedCnt / totalDFUsCnt * 80) +
                                                            (udasLoadedCnt / totalDFUsCnt * 80) + (histLoadedCnt / totalDFUsCnt * 80) +
                                                            (fcstLoadedCnt / totalDFUsCnt * 80)) / 500d);

                                                if (progress != 0.0) {
                                                    progressBar.setValue((int) (progress * 100));
                                                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(500);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                }
                            });
                } catch (PrivilegedActionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        public void finished() {
          }

        public void setBusinessObjectUserContext(BusinessObjectUserContext iUc) {
            uc = iUc;
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: This has the smell of trying to accomplish something on the UI from a different thread other than the `EventDispatch` thread. You should make sure that you use something like `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` when working on anything that is not explicitly marked as thread safe in the docs.

Comment: Yes your right this code is perhaps not written in a thread safe manner. The wrong thing we are doing here was to update the progress bar from the construct(doINBackground) of swing worker.I hav emodev that code out but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "stuck", I have had code where progress seemed to halt because an associated timer had been garbage collected.

In other words, I had to move the timer variable to an object that would keep its instance around.

And before I moved the variable, there was no runtime error, it would just stop working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I want the progress bar and the dialog to dispose. When the dispose method is called but that is perhaps not happening. I don't think this has to do with any component being barbage collected.